reorder the levels of a factor column in R to appear horizontally matching in two plots
i have  a simulated data frame in R :
library(tidyverse)
library(ggstats)
library(patchwork)

set.seed(123)
likert_levels <- c(
  "1" = "Very  Dissatisfied",
  "2" = "Dissatisfied",
  "3" = "Neutral",
  "4" = "Satisfied",
  "5" = "Very  Satisfied")

df = data.frame(
  var = sample(c("yes", "no"), 50, replace = TRUE),
  A= sample(likert_levels, 50, replace = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.factor)) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(across(-var, ~ factor(.x, levels = likert_levels)))

# starting plot (removed facets and ensured order of 'var' factor)
likert <- df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(id,var), names_to="group") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=var) %>%
  gglikert(c(df$var))  # removed facet_rows=vars(group)

# get the order of years according to n
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(id, var), names_to = "group") %>%
  count(group, var) %>%
  mutate(var = factor(var, levels = c("no", "yes"))) %>%
  arrange(var) %>%
  select(var) %>%
  distinct()

likert$data <- likert$data %>%
  mutate(.question = factor(.question, levels = c("no", "yes")))

# create the barplot (removed facets and ensured order of 'var' factor)
bar <- df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(id, var), names_to = "group") %>%
  count(group, var) %>%
  mutate(var = factor(var, levels = c("no", "yes"))) %>%  # ensure 'no' comes first
  ggplot(aes(x = n, y = fct_reorder(var, n))) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_label(aes(label = n),
             color = "white", hjust = 1,
             fill = NA, label.size = 0) +
  labs(y = NULL) +  # removed facet_wrap
  likert$theme

# plot them side by side
likert + bar + plot_layout(widths = c(0.8, 0.2), guides = "collect") &
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")



resulting to

but i want to relevel or reoder the var column in order to show from top to bottom the "no" level and then the "yes" level in both the likert and the bar chart . How can i do it in R ?

You have mutate(var = factor(var, levels = c("no", "yes"))) # ensure 'no' comes first, this is correct.  But then in your plot you use y = fct_reorder(var, n) which reorders based on the number of responses. Keep the ordering of the levels with no first, then use y = var in the plot, not y = reorder....

@GregorThomas if i write y = var again the yes comes first.But i want the no first.

Oh, sorry, I didn't see your note about "top to bottom". On y-axes, the first values go at the bottom. If you want "no" at the top then use mutate(var = factor(var, levels = c("yes", "no"))), switching the order of the levels.

@GregorThomas wrap it all in a proper answer please . i will appreciate it

Side note - please don't put rm(list = ls()) in your question code. I almost ran that inadvertently which would have been very annoying for what I was working on.

Y-axes in ggplot start from the bottom. So if you want "no" at the top, it needs to be your last factor level, not your first.
## Instead of this
var = factor(var, levels = c("no", "yes"))
## use this
var = factor(var, levels = c("yes", "no"))

Also, once your factors levels are ordered correctly, don't change them. y = fct_reorder(var, n) will reorder by the count, which is not what you want.
